# Refreshing Crystal Reports through Excel Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, macros, vba, crystal-reports

At work we have an ancient Ingress database that wont allow me to make links between tables using the SQL Query editor in Excel 2007.

My current solution is to generate the data in Crystal Reports, export it to excel and write a macro to then grab that data.

This works for my own purposes, but I am only contracted till June and would like to make these reports as automated as possible.

Is there a way to refresh the crystal report through an excel macro? Maybe through the likes of a batch file or shell script? Dont know much about either of those options but with only a minor java coding background am not even really sure what I should be looking to for the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To resolve the issue, i created an odbc connection to the database and used the data sources tab in excel to directly import the data into excel

Comment: if this worked for you, you should answer your own question and mark it as such.

Comment: Will do. When i originally found the answer i did not have enough rep to answer my own question. Will provide a more detailed answer below